# Plot the total percentage of last n rows in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a taxa dataset with frequency distribution of over 100 genus. Here is a sample data.

```
structure(list(Genus = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", N"), 
Frequency = c(1580, 1456, 927, 900, 625, 611, 535, 534, 452, 341, 323, 314, 254, 247)),
row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to use ggplot to creat a stack barplot for the proportions of each genus. But I would only want to show the exact proportions of first 5 genus, and group the remaining together to show a total proportion of them. Would this be possible to do in ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fct_lump_n` to lump together the low-frequency observations:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Genus = fct_lump_n(Genus, n = 5, w = Frequency)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = '', y = Frequency, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Dark2') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Or if you want labelled proportions:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Genus = fct_lump_n(Genus, n = 5, w = Frequency)) %>%
  summarise(Frequency = sum(Frequency), .by = Genus) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = '', y = Frequency, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill(), color = 'gray50') +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Frequency / sum(Frequency))),
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Pastel1') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]